# Prove the formula $1+r\cdot \cos(α)+r^{2}\cos(2α)+\cdots+r^{n}\cos(nα)=\dfrac{r^{n+2}\cos(nα)-r^{n+1}\cos[(n+1)α]-r\cosα+1}{r^{2}-2r\cdot \cos(α)+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, summation, power-series

For $r,a\in\mathbb{R}:\; r^{2}-2r\cos{a}+1\neq 0$ prove the formula $$1+r\cdot \cos(a)+r^{2}\cos(2a)+\cdots+r^{n}\cos(na)=\dfrac{r^{n+2}\cos(na)-r^{n+1}\cos[(n+1)a]-r\cdot \cos(a)+1}{r^{2}-2r\cdot \cos(a)+1}$$
Solution:
Set $z=re^{ia}$ then
$$1+z+z^{2}+\cdots+z^{n}=\dfrac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}=\dfrac{r^{n+1}e^{(n+1)ia}-1}{re^{ia}-1}=\dfrac{(r^{n+1}e^{ia}-1)(re^{ia}-1)}{|re^{ia}-1|^{2}}.$$
Here
$|re^{ia}-1|^{2}=|r(\cos{a}+i\sin{a})-1|^{2}=|r\cos{a}-1+ir\sin{a}|^{2}=(r\cos{a}-1)^{2}+(r\sin{a})^{2}=r^{2}\cos^{2}a-2r\cos{a}+1+r^{2}\sin^{2}a=r^{2}-2r\cos{a}+1$
and
$(r^{n+1}e^{ia}-1)(re^{ia}-1)=r^{n+2}\cos(na)-r^{n+1}\cos[(n+1)a]-r\cdot \cos(a)+1=r^{n+2}e^{(n+2)ai}-r^{n+1}e^{(n+1)a}-re^{ia}+1 =\left(\cos{\left[(n+2)a\right]}+i\sin{\left[(n+2)a\right]}\right)-r^{n+1}\left(\cos{\left[(n+1)a\right]}+i\sin{\left[(n+1)a\right]}\right)-r\left(\cos{a}+i\sin{a}\right)+1=?$

Comment: _"cannot prove that $(^{+1}^{}−1)(^{}−1)=^{+2}()−^{+1}[(+1)]−⋅()+1$"_ - What exactly do you not understand about this?

Comment: @Dstarred i can go up until a point. (see in the solution)

Answer (score 1):

HINT…when you sum the series and get $$\frac{r^{n+1}e^{(n+1)i\alpha}-1}{re^{i\alpha}-1}$$

Multiply top and bottom by the conjugate of the denominator which is $$re^{-i\alpha}-1$$

Comment: is there a chance you can help with the following: $r^{n+2}\cos{(na)}-r^{n+1}\cos{\left[(n+1)a\right]}-r\cos{a}+1-r^{n+2}i\sin{(na)}-r^{n+1}i\sin{\left[(n+1)a\right]}$$
$$+r\cdot i\sin{a}=r^{n+2}\cos{(na)}-r^{n+1}\cos{\left[(n+1)a\right]}-r\cos{a}+1$

Comment: To sum the series in the question you only need the **real** part of the summation so just ignore the imaginary terms and you have the result

Comment: However what I have to say for the solution to be complete. Why in the Euler's formula $e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$ we only keep the $\cos{x}.$

Comment: The real part of $re^{i\alpha}$ is $r\cos\alpha$